# Joining pointcuts on AspectJ

Tags: java, android, aspectj, aop

I'm new to AspectJ even though I knew about this AOP methodology for many years.
Now it's my first time to use it on my Android app, and want to ask few questions regarding to it.

I have Java code:

```
    private void mainView() {
        ... (some code)
        <A>
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mView = findViewById(R.id.Main_Root);
    mView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        <B>
        ... (some code)
    }
```

I have the following AspectJ code:

```
public aspect mainViewTiming {
    pointcut callSetContentViewTiming():
        call(* android.app.Activity.setContentView(..))
        && withincode(void mainView(..))
    ;

    pointcut callFindViewById(): 
        call(* android.app.Activity.findViewById(..))
        && withincode(void mainView(..))
    ;

    pointcut callSetOnTouchListener(): 
        call (* android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(..))
        && withincode(void mainView(..))
    ;

 }
```

Now my question is how to I use AspectJ and calculate the time it takes to run from  to ?

I have 3 pointcuts and I would like to know what's the best way to combine them to have this effect? From this link I learned that I can use "cflow":
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html

```
before(): cflow(callSetContentViewTiming()) && cflow(callFindViewById()) && callSetOnTouchListener() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

But I wasn't sure if that's right.  And how do I calculate the difference between  and  when combining the pointcuts. And is there something like "after()" ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an "after()". But I'm not sure you are using cflow right. cflow means control flow. It is a pointcut that hits whenever a certain pointcut is on the stack. Whenever you are inside a method call (that is inside a method call, that is inside a method call) matching that other pointcut.

What you want here is to set start before the first method call and set end after the last method call. The middle method call is irrelevant so I eliminated that pointcut.

```
public aspect MainViewTiming {

    pointcut mainView() : withincode(void mainView(..));

    pointcut callSetContentViewTiming() :
        call(* android.app.Activity.setContentView(..)) && mainView();

    pointcut callSetOnTouchListener() :
        call (* android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(..)) && mainView();

    before() : callSetContentViewTiming() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    after() : callSetOnTouchListener() {
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

Note that there will be only one instance of this aspect.